# How to add enter to this string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

can you help me on this?
I have this code which is a part of my program :

```
Scanner a5 = new Scanner(System.in); 
            while(a5.hasNextLine()) //store every line in mail message until user type "." on a seperate line
            {
                String text = a5.nextLine();
                if (text.charAt(0) != '.')
                    {txt.add(text);}
                else if(text.charAt(0) == '.'  )
                {break;}
            }
```

I want user to type a message and until he doesn't type "." in a separate line he can add more lines. but my problem is when I press enter I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String ind
ex out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at MyPMC.main(MyPMC.java:51)
```

how can I fix it so it also add empty line to my string?
example:
when I type this in message it work ok :

```
Hi
my name is jack
.
```

but when I press enter after second sentence I get error and my program crash, I can't type like this:

```
Hi 
My name is jack

this is message

.
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type only enter the Scanner returns an empty String. When you try to get an empty String's first character with `text.charAt(0)`, you go out of range and the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

A quick fix would be to check the length of the String before using charAt as follows:

```
if (text.length() > 0 && text.charAt(0) != '.')
```

Comment: I still get the error when I press enter, I can type like this :

Comment: Hi my name is jack  then empty line then this is end then .

Comment: You are accessing charAt(0) in two different places, did you correct them both?

Comment: now the problem is it doesn't add empty line to strings, but I get the error anymore.

Comment: Try if(text.length == 0 || text.charAt(0) != '.') in the first block, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for an empty string, there is no 0th character, so `text.charAt(0)` fails.

Instead, you can use `text.startsWith(".")` to test for the first character (or first few characters), and `text.isEmpty()` to test for an empty input, i.e., when the user hits enter without writing any text first.

Also, since your second `if` condition is exactly the negation of the first, you can just use `else` here.

Answer (score 0):

Add simple length check and continue if 0